# Swing, from JPanel to design view

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I started creating a `JPanel` in NetBeans 8.0, adding many components (Button, Label...). Everything works fine.

Now I'd like to see the design view implemented in the `JPanelForm` (which I don't have because I didn't add a `JPanelForm` but I only created a `JPanel` in a class). 
Is there a way to "export" my Panel into a `JPanelForm` or should I have to create a new `JPanelForm` and insert all my components?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans 8.0; I'm askig if there is a way to split from code to design view. The design view I'm talking about, is this one: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-6323/images/ep-bpel-designer.gif

Comment: So you coded the components layout by hand? Then there is no easy way to put this into the form designer.